# Using Typescript unable to assign a value to the Class level variable inside fs.createReadStream

Tags: csv, variables, typescript

I am new to **typescript** and have a scenario where in I need to read data from a **csv** file and assign the values to a class level `Map<>` variable.
Following is the code I am trying out but facing below issues:-

a) The VS Code intellisence ***doesn't*** prompt me with name of my class level `Map<>` variable when I try something like `this.NameOfMapVariable` inside my `fs.createReadStream` **function**

b) Even if I ignore the intellisence thingy and try and write the code for assigning the value, then at runtime I get the error:-

> cannot read property set of Undefined

Code Snippet of my `CSVHelper.ts` file:-

```
import * as csvParse from 'csv-parser';
import fs = require('fs');
var parse = csvParse.Parser;

export class CSVHelper {
  public TestSpecificData = new Map<string, string>();

  public fetchTestSpecificData(clsName: string, mthdName: string): Map<string, string> {
    fs.createReadStream('../TestData/TestSpecificData.csv').pipe(csvParse()).on('data', function (data) {
      if (data.TestClass == clsName && data.TestMethod == mthdName)
        this.TestSpecificData.set(data.Key.toString(), data.Value.toString());

    }
    )   

    return this.TestSpecificData;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are defining a function, that is called by the event `data`. The keyword `this` gets a new context by this call, where `TestSpecificData` indeed does not exist.

You can try a lambda expression, where `this` stays in your expected context:

```
fs.createReadStream('../TestDataTestSpecificData.csv')
    .pipe(csvParse())
    .on('data', (data) => {
       if (data.TestClass == clsName && data.TestMethod == mthdName) {
           this.TestSpecificData.set(data.Key.toString(), data.Value.toString());
       }
     });
```

Comment: Yes, I will but a follow up question to this. The whole purpose of doing this is to be able to return TestSpecificData at the end of the function:- fetchTestSpecificData.
But, I think because of async behavior of typescript, I don't get desired value in TestSpecificData Map<> variable
Any idea how to get it resolved?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. You are returning the map before the data arrives. There are several possibilities to make this work. Either use a callback function, a Promise or an Observable.

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve this using promise chains but not able to. Can you please provide me with some directions of how to solve this using promises?

Comment: I don't know where you problem starts. But you have to return a Promise like here https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/332